# Define a class in Python and import into Rust module, but it "cannot be converted"

Tags: python, class, rust, data-conversion, pyo3

This may be documented somewhere in the PyO3 documents, but I couldn't find it.

I make a class like this in Python:

```
class ProgressData():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time_ms = 0
        self.last_progress_percent = 0.0
```

... I instantiate it and pass it to a Rust module with the following signature:

```
#[pyfunction]
fn index_documents(py: Python, progress_data: ProgressData) -> PyResult<()> {
    ...
```

I've defined an "equivalent" `struct` in the Rust module:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
#[pyclass]
pub struct ProgressData {
    start_time_ms: usize,
    last_progress_percent: f64,
}
```

and I've added this as one of the exportable classes:

```
#[pymodule]
#[pyo3(name = "populate_index")]
fn my_extension(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(index_documents, m)?)?;
    m.add_class::<HandlingFramework>()?;
    m.add_class::<TextDocument>()?;
    m.add_class::<ProgressData>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

... but it doesn't work: I get

> argument 'progress_data': 'ProgressData' object cannot be converted to 'ProgressData'

No further explanation.

The above classes "HandlingFramework" and "TextDocument" are created in Rust and exported to Python where their properties and methods can be used. Is there a way to do it the other way round (make in Python, use in Rust)? Or maybe the only way is to make a factory function in the Rust module to deliver a `ProgressData` object to the Python, put data in this, and then re-export it to another function in the Rust module?

I'd also like to define a couple of methods for `ProgressData`: again, any way to define this in Python, but have it accepted by Rust as a shoe-in for an equivalent Rust `struct` + `impl`?

Comment: The `ProgressData` objects defined in Python and Rust are completely unrelated, even if they have the same name. You have to pick one or the other and use that from the other.

Comment: OK... can you point me to some example or documentation on this (make in Python, use in Rust)?

Comment: The [calling python from rust code](https://pyo3.rs/v0.20.2/python_from_rust) has a bunch of those. It does that from Rust, but the actual operations are the same, you receive a [`PyAny`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/types/struct.PyAny.html) (possibly via [`PyObject`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/type.PyObject.html)), then you use python-level access (getattr/setattr/call/call_method) to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I was looking for. Slightly concerned about the use of `py` there, as my entire Rust module is run in a Gil-free closure: `py.allow_threads(move || { ...`. I wonder if that's going to be a problem. ... will see.

Answer (score 1):

Masklinn pointed me to the right part of the manual.

But in fact I found that implementing a factory method solution was perhaps the simplest solution for me in this case: no need to mess around with the `py` object.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
#[pyclass]
pub struct ProgressData {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    start_time_ms: usize,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    last_progress_percent: f64,
}

#[pyfunction]
fn new_progress_data(py: Python) -> ProgressData {
    ProgressData {
        start_time_ms: 0,
        last_progress_percent: 0.0,
    }
}
```

... I can quickly rustle up an instance in the Python code and having manipulated the data re-export it to the Rust `index_documents` function ... and the `ProgressData` parameter is accepted without a murmur. Obviously the Python class definition has been deleted.